# DataTable to Excel Word and PDF

Tags: javascript, c#

The code below show only 10 records because of my filters

```
m.getData = function (options, callback) {
table = $('#auditTrailTable').DataTable();
var info = table.page.info();
options.RecordsToSkip = info.start;
    options.RecordsToTake = info.length;

    var data = table.ajax.params();

    options.SortDirection = data.order[0].dir;
    options.ColumnName = data.columns[data.order[0].column].data;

    var paramDTO = {
        param: options,
        searchValue: '',
        dateFrom: m.filterDateFrom(),
        dateTo: m.filterDateTo()
    };
    var url = '/AuditTrail/Find';

    knock.AjaxBlockElement(paramDTO, url, '', function (result) {
        if (result.Data != undefined) {
            callback(result);
        }
    });

};
```

The code below is my function to export the current page shown to excel only

```
 m.exportToExcel = function () {
    var oTable = $('#auditTrailTable').DataTable();
    $.fn.DataTable.Export.excel(oTable, {
        filename: 'AuditTrail_Export',
        title: 'WebSOA Audit Trail',
        message: '',
        header: ['Activity', 'Name', 'Username', 'Timestamp'],
        fields: ["Activity", "Name", "Username", "TimestampString"]
    });
}
;
```

My target is to export all records that aren't shown to excel/pdf and word but I only want to show is the current page with 10 records. Meaning all records from Page 2 up to the last page will be exported.